# How to log changes to stored objects/records in Java

Tags: java, pojo

In troubleshooting operations issues, I'm finding it difficult at times to diagnose a problem without more details.  I see from timestamps that a merchant record changed on a particular date, for example, and the processing of transactions on the prior day is called into question.  Logging what changed could help quickly rule out possibilities.

Are there any utilities out there that do that sort of comparison automatically?  I'd like it to be able to do something like:

```
String logDelta=SomeLibrary.describeChanges(bean1, bean2);
```

I'd be hoping for a one-liner with something like:

```
"lastName{'Onassis','Kennedy Onassis'}, favoriteNumber{16,50}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called an audit trail or an audit log and it's generally done in the database using triggers or stored procedures to make a copy of the row in the database being changed with the name of the user and the timestamp. It's very common to do this for compliance reasons. I haven't seen any packages that manage it for you because it's usually very tightly coupled to the database design.. you don't necessarily want a copy of every single row or every field, and it can become very expensive to do this in a highly transactional environment.

Try googling 'audit trail'

Comment: Thanks for shining the light on some proper terminology.  Even if I kept full historical records in a database rather than logging the deltas to syslog, I would still want to visually reduce the information to only the changes.

Comment: Yes, that's a fairly trivial database report to write.

Comment: True, but I'd rather not maintain custom code for each individual object when a generalized function would do.  I also have no interest in closely coupling a solution with a database.